# How to transliterate a string from Cyrillic to Latin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Story model. User can enter a title in Russian and I need to save alias, which will take transform from Cyrillic to Latin(not translation). For example, 'привет' will be 'privet', not 'hi'.

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: So you mean *transcription* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(linguistics)) ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes

Comment: I think [transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) is closer than *transcription*.

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov do you know how to translate in django ? I mean is this your question

Comment: @Shakil yes, alias can't be entered and should automatically saved when story is created

Comment: @MarkMeyer transliteration makes more sense

Comment: You need to manually create LocalMessages, only if you have that translation then that can be done using `gettext` or `gettext_lazy()`. At first you need to go through [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the actual aliasing you can use [python-slugify](https://pypi.org/project/python-slugify/) to do your trans[scription|literation].  This will turn it into a URL safe ascii version, taking care of cyrillic, chinese, german, etc.

```
>>> from slugify import slugify
>>> slugify('привет')
'privet'
>>> slugify('привет, привет', separator=' ')
'privet privet'
```

As for how to do it to your model, there are many many ways.  Here is one using DRF serializers.  I recommend using a different serializer for create vs. get/list/etc.

```
class StoryCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    other_field = CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ['title', 'other_field']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs['alias'] = slugify(attrs['title'])
        return attrs


ser = StoryCreateSerializer(request.data)
ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
print(ser.validated_data)
    { "title", "My Title", "alias": "my-title", "other_field": "x" }
```

Comment: Slugify is for urls mainly - what actually does the transliteration is [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) library.

Comment: I think that was mentioned in the first line of the answer, so I'm not sure what you think you are adding here, its not reddit. You can definitely rebuild this widely used library from base tools, just as you are free to re-implement `requests` from the base `urllib`.  You can and should add a new answer showing how to do the thing they want using only that library, though, it could be helpful.

Comment: And as I said, as if predicting your comment by 3 years, "This will turn it into a URL safe ascii version".  They are doing this for a URL, though they don't say so in the question.  They most definitely aren't translating it, or using it for searching.  You really should add an answer using the `Unidecode` library directly to implement this, it could be helpful to someone (me included)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [model's save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods):

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.alias:
            self.alias = your_transliteration_function(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```